# Why does this pandas calculation return an error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I started learning Python some few hours ago and run into this problem
The script below runs correctly and expected output is generated

```
import pandas as pd
brics = pd.read_csv('G:/brics.csv', index_col = 0)
brics
```

However when I use this code (which is intended to calculate the density)

```
brics["density"] = brics["population"] / brics["area"] * 1000000
```

I get an error message below:

```
d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 'population'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7f590cb7a5d0> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 brics = pd.read_csv("G:/brics.csv", index_col = 0)
----> 3 brics["density"] = brics["population"] / brics["area"] * 1000000
      4 brics
d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]
d:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 'population'
```

Comment: That means there's no column called `'population'` in your DataFrame.

Comment: Wild guess: case problem "Population" <-> "population"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
brics.info()
```

and confirm the column exists, because pandas doesn't think it does. Which likely means it's labeled something other than what you think it is.

Comment: Or: `brics.columns`.

Comment: @NewtoR Glad that helped.